# How do I drive an ERV directly from EAC output of a Thermo Pride O6 Furnace?

Tags: hvac, erv

I have an ERV driven by a relay controlled by an Air Cycler.

I recently installed a Thermo Pride O6 furnace. The O6 has 120 VAC output to control EAC. Can I plug my ERV directly into this outlet instead of going through a relay?

Update with additional info:

Right now I have 2 Air Cyclers (one for each zone), that control 2 relays connected in OR configuration that in turn drive the remote controller of my ERV.

My problems are:

1. We do not use Air Cyclers during spring/summer/fall when we live with open windows but we still want air exchange during days when we run A/C.
2. My connection to ERV is clanky in several respects. It will be really nice to plug my ERV directly into my furnace and let it run as long as the heating/cooling fan is running.

My main question is does the EAC output provide enough power for a 0.25 HP motor in my ERV?

Update 2:

I found a description of the control unit (rebranded) used by my system [Renewaire PTL](https://www.renewaire.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/PTL_InstructionSheet_140465_008_APR20.pdf).

From that, I learned that I can control my ERV with a single relay with 150 ohm 1/8 wt resistor in the circuit. It seems in sync with the electrics of my ERV, which supplies the control circuit with 24 VAC + diode.

So my plans are as follows I will use 115 VAC relay, and 150 ohm 2wt rated resistor (1/8 wt seems too low).

My questions could be reformulated as:

1. What 115 VAC relay should I use to control a 24 VAC circuit?
2. Are there some small boxes to house the relay and the resistor?
   C. Are there any restrictions on resistor type?

Comment: tell us what happened

Comment: Does the AirCycler control have control over the air-handler/furnace blower fan as of right now?

Comment: Yes, this is the primary role of AirCycler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this [hobby box](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B083H9D3P1), this [relay](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B087G6D24G), and this[resitor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07RVD39C2).  The 150 Ohm 1/8 W resistor looked too scary for a 24V circuit, so I used a 5 W resistor. The schematic is from [the control box description](https://www.renewaire.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/PTL_InstructionSheet_140465_008_APR20.pdf). Works fine.

Comment: I wouldn't use an Amazon (read: Cheeseshop) special for this; something like a RIB with suitable ratings would have been *far* more apropos for the application, although a typical HVAC fan relay will have 115V rated contacts on it